# How to set the gap between lines of a section

Tags: line-spacing

I want to change the gap between the lines of a section.

[image: gap]

MWE is below;

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=turkish,english,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\myonevspace}{14pt}% <-- Define a macro \myonehalfvspace
\newcommand*{\myonehalfvspace}{21pt}% <-- Define a macro \myonehalfvspace
\newcommand*{\mytwovspace}{28pt}% <-- Define a macro \mytwovspace

% Chapter heading \titlespacing*{command}{left}{before-sep}{after-sep}[right-sep]
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{1cm}{0cm plus 4pt minus 2pt}{\myonehalfvspace plus 2pt minus 2pt}
% Section heading
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection.}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{1cm}{\myonehalfvspace plus 4pt minus 2pt}{\myonehalfvspace plus 2pt minus 2pt}
% Subsection heading
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{1cm}{\mytwovspace plus 4pt minus 2pt}{\myonehalfvspace plus 2pt minus 2pt}
% Subsubsection heading
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection.}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{1cm}{\mytwovspace plus 4pt minus 2pt}{\myonehalfvspace plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Long Section Title Long Section Title Long Section Title Long Section Title Long Section Title}


\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: it's the baseline spacing as specified by the font size command (`\normalsize` here)   why are you specifying lengths to 6 decimal places 20.775861pt  that is smaller than tex can store (it is equal to 20.775860pt ) and doesn't look any different to 21pt? Especially as you are allowing it to stretch or shrink by 2pt in any case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, I rounded the numbers up. Is this only an advice or Is this related the question?

Comment: No the answer to the question is as I said `\baselineskip` which is set by the font size command (although you could set it again after the `\normalsize` if you wish) no it was just a comment as you were asking about spacing but your existing spaces looked so weird.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle where should I use the \baselineskip command? Before the section name? It does not work.